# Technique used by Alarmy for Controlling System Volume During Alarm?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

While studying the behavior of the Alarmy app, I've observed that it instantly sets the device's system volume to its maximum level the moment an alarm goes off, irrespective of the app's background or foreground status. In contrast, my own application experiences a noticeable delay in modifying the volume after it's been relegated to the background. I'm keen on understanding how Alarmy can achieve such accurate volume control at the precise instant the alarm rings.

Would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.